# Radio button won't show/hide divs

Tags: html, css, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to use css to show and hide div's via radio button.
is there a problem with my code :<

here's the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/uaLmjnjc/

the css

```
#logo-as-is:checked ~ #upload-image-selected, #select-from-library-selected{
    display:none;   
}

#logo-upload-img:checked ~ #upload-image-selected{
    display:block;
}

#logo-upload-img:checked ~ #select-from-library-selected{
    display:none;
}

#logo-select-library:checked ~ #select-from-library-selected{
    display:block;
}

#logo-select-library:checked ~ #upload-image-selected{
    display:none;
}

#upload-image-selected{
    display:none;
}

#select-from-library-selected{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tilde selector

> The general sibling combinator selector is very similar to the
>   adjacent sibling combinator selector. The difference is that the
>   element being selected doesn't need to immediately succeed the first
>   element, but can appear anywhere after it.

So they have to share the same parent, they cannot  just be *anywhere* on the page like you've done, so for example

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" class="iradio" name="logoselection" id="logo-as-is" />
    <label for="logo-as-is">Hide div</label>
    <div id="hideme">Hidden when radio checked</div>
</div>

#logo-as-is:checked ~ #hideme {
    display:none;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L3t8suuy/

would work, whereas if the div you're trying to hide does not share the same parent as the radio button, it won't work

http://jsfiddle.net/L3t8suuy/1/

This leaves you with two choices for what you're trying to accomplish, restructure your HTML abit so that all elements that you're trying to hide also share the same parent **and follow** the element that when selected hides them. Or, unfortunately, resort to using javascript.

Comment: @Gilbert unfortunately not, CSS simply lacks this sort of functionality. If you wanted to keep your HTML as it is and do what you want to do, you'd have to resort to using javascript to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to achieve the same.

Its algorithm would go like -

Check if the corresponding radio is checked or not.

IF checked then hide the div.